# How can I change "ADD CONFIGURATION" to "Add Configuration" in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I  installed `Material Theme UI`（a plugin for JetBrains IDE） choose a new theme.
When I debug code, I find PyCharm "Add Configuration" is changed to "ADD CONFIGURATION". It's no longer case sensitive!

[image: the UI element changed]

[image: the UI element original]

Comment: @bad_coder I think this theme change some setting in pycharm, it can be solved by setting in pycharm, but I dont know how to set

Comment: @bad_coder     I add screenshots, can u see ?

Comment: @bad_coder U r right. I disable the plugin, solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins are generally compiled Java applications that can change PyCharm's UI interface. The problem you describe seems like a styling inconsistency (we can also call it a bug) of the [Material theme UI plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui). Those UI elements can't generally be changed using settings, so if you don't like the current capitalization your only chance is uninstalling the plugin or post a bug report on the [Material Theme UI's GitHub](https://github.com/mallowigi/material-theme-issues/issues).